# Why is my ruby method always returning true?

Tags: ruby, class, collections, boolean

From codeschool's ruby-bits course, I am trying to understand how these classes work- I have a `Game` class and a collection class called `Library` that stores a collection of games.

```
class Game
  attr_accessor :name, :year, :system
  attr_reader :created_at

  def initialize(name, options={})
    self.name = name
    self.year = options[:year]
    self.system = options[:system]
    @created_at = Time.now
  end


  def ==(game)
    name == game.name && 
    system == game.system &&
    year == game.year
  end
end
```

Library class:

```
class Library
  attr_accessor :games

  def initialize(*games)
    self.games = games
  end

  def has_game?(*games)
    for game in self.games
      return true if game == game
    end
    false
  end
end
```

Now I create some games:

```
contra = Game.new('Contra', {
  year: 1994,
  system: 'nintendo'
})

mario = Game.new('Mario', {
  year: 1996,
  system: 'SNES'
})

sonic = Game.new('Sonic', {
  year: 1993,
  system: 'SEGA'
})
```

and instantiate a new collection:

```
myCollection = Library.new(mario, sonic)
```

When I try to find if a certain game is in `myCollection` using the `has_game?` method, I always get `true`

`puts myCollection.has_game?(contra) #=> returns **true**` even though this has never been inserted as part of the collection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because `game == game` is always true.

Comment: So is the `==(games)` instance method in the Game class that's the problem? How do I fix this? I need to check if the game is part of the collection or not

Comment: No, the problem is that you're comparing `game` to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things that are wrong here:

1. Instead of using `self.XXXX` to create instance variables you should 
   use `@XXXX`, it accesses the values directly, using self actually performs 
   another method call, refer here for more details: [Instance variable: self vs @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693243/instance-variable-self-vs)
2. As the others mentioned `game == game` will always return `true`, the answer that 
   was already posted doesn't allow for passing more than a single game to `has_game?`

Here are my changes that work correctly:

```
class Game
  attr_accessor :name, :year, :system
  attr_reader :created_at

  def initialize(name, options={})
    @name       = name
    @year       = options[:year]
    @system     = options[:system]
    @created_at = Time.now
  end


  def ==(game)
    @name == game.name && 
    @system == game.system &&
    @year == game.year
  end
end

class Library
  attr_accessor :games

  def initialize(*games)
    @games = games
  end

  # only returns true if this Library
  # has ALL of the games passed to has_game? 
  def has_game?(*_games)
    _games.each do |game|
      return false if not @games.include?(game)
    end

    return true
  end
end

contra = Game.new('Contra', {
  year: 1994,
  system: 'nintendo'
})

mario = Game.new('Mario', {
  year: 1996,
  system: 'SNES'
})

sonic = Game.new('Sonic', {
  year: 1993,
  system: 'SEGA'
})

myCollection = Library.new(mario, sonic)
puts "Collection has Contra? #{myCollection.has_game?(contra)}"
puts "Collection has Sonic and Mario #{myCollection.has_game?(sonic, mario)}"
```

output:

```
Collection has Contra? false
Collection has Sonic and Mario true
```

Comment: your "has_game?()" method returns only whether the last game is included in @games... it would probably be easier with an array intersect, or you could iterate thus: def has_game?(*_games);_games.map{|game|@games.include?(game)}.all?;end

Comment: @Pavling You are right, I forgot to break out in the event of false.

Comment: @Pavling I ended up re-writing the method in a better way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
return true if game == game
```

I think this statement may cause problem.

It is always true.

You may want something like this:

```
def has_game?(wanted)
  for game in self.games
    return true if game == wanted
  end
  false
end
```