# Why is 'self' necessary here instead of an instance variable?

Tags: ruby

In a lesson from codeschool, the code in the top-left block is demonstrated to be incorrect.

"Of course it is", I say to myself. I've learned it should be `@name = name`. What's the new problem? Why is "self" necessary here instead? See my working code below:

[image]

```
class UserList
    attr_accessor :name
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end

list = UserList.new('celebrities')
list.name
```

Comment: currently perusing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693243/instance-variable-self-vs?rq=1

Comment: Just to elaborate a little on the answers below, here the method `name=()`, which is generated by `attr_accessor`, must have a receiver to which the method is applied.  `self.name=` specifies the receiver to be `self`, which here equals an instance of the class `UserList`.  If you did not specify a receiver (just `name=`), Ruby assumes the receiver is `self`, so here it's optional.  Note that there are other situations where the use of `self` is not optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is not necessary here. What you are doing is equivalent. Either way is fine.

Comment: In this specific case it is equivalent but that's only because the `name=` method is being defined by `attr_accessor`, if you had a `name=` method that actually did something interesting then `@name = 'name'` and `self.name = 'name'` would not be equivalent.

Comment: ah... so codeschool should have shown me that special circumstance... maybe it's in an upcoming lesson

Comment: @dwilbank: I hope so, that example is pretty shallow and misleading (unless there is a bit more meat to the notes that I can't see). There is a bit of possible ambiguity in `a = b`, is that assigning `b` to a local variable `a` or is it calling the `a=` method on `self`? The ambiguity is resolved to be the "local variable `a`" case because otherwise there'd be no sane way to create a local variable (unless there was a keyword (`my`, `var`, ...) for that); if you want to call the `a=` mutator method then you have to resolve the ambiguity by hand and say `self.a =`.

Answer (score 0):

`self.name =` calls the `name=` method which sets the instance variable `@name`. What you are doing is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Codeschool is introducing `attr_accessor` here. And you are right the lines

```
@name     = name
self.name = name
```

are equivalent.

But on the one hand why choose `attr_accessor` (and not `attr_reader`) and then write `@name=`? One part of the learning is that `attr_accessor` creates a setter method. Using `attr_accessor` with `@name=` is kind of useless.

And on the other hand they wanted to point out an other important detail: Even if `attr_accessor` creates a method `def name=(name)`, non of this will work:

```
name = name
name = 'Bart'
```

Because it would never change the underlying `@name` variable nor even touch the method created with `attr_accessor`. It would change the local variable `name`.

And this is an important learning. Know the difference between `name=` and `self.name=`.