# In object.initialize, is it better to use self. over @?

Tags: ruby

There's a convention to reference an object's attributes over its instance variables, where possible. [Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321721330) says:

> Always wrap instance variables in accessor methods instead of directly
>   referring to variables...

This is shown with an example, which I've paraphrased:

```
class Gear
  attr_reader :chainring, :cog
  ...
  def ratio
    # this is bad
    # @chainring / @cog.to_f
    # this is good
    chainring / cog.to_f
end
```

The most common way I see to create a new object with an instance variable is this:

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end
end
```

`@title=` directly accesses the instance variable `title`. **Assuming we are following the the 'attribute over instance variable' convention**, is it more appropriate to use `self.title=`, [which would tell the object to send itself the message `title=`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1693319/173634), thereby using the attribute write method, over the instance variable directly?

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
  def initialize(title)
    self.title = title
  end
end
```

The book talks about 'attribute over instance variable' with reference to reading an instance variable, but doesn't it also apply to writing?

Comment: In some case `self.feature=` is more preferably than `@feature=`, generally in that case when assignment to `self.` shell do more actiona then just assignment. In second, here: https://github.com/3aHyga/ruby-style-guide you can see that good style `self.feature=` is encontered only once, when the complex assignment (it means that not just assisnment to a instance variable) is occurred. In case of read always used construction like `feature == "value"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The book talks about 'attribute over instance variable' with reference
>   to reading an instance variable, but doesn't it also apply to writing?

Yes, it also applies to writing. However, the `initialize` method is special because it is responsible for setting up the object. When you use a setter method, you do that because the setter might be doing some extra work (e.g. attribute-setters in Rails). In an initializer, you usually don't want to have any side effects, so you access instance variables directly.

Answer (score 0):

At first, in some case `self.feature=` is more preferably than `@feature=`, generally in that case, when assignment to `feature` property shell do more actions, then just assignment. For example, in a database access methods.

At second, in [the good ruby style guide](http://github.com/3aHyga/ruby-style-guide) you can see that good style `self.feature=` is encontered only once, when the complex assignment is occurred. It means that not just assisnment to a instance variable. In case of read, construction like feature == "value"  is always used.